# Rabbit Template back off policy with automatic recovery disabled

Tags: spring-rabbit

I've configured the CachingConnectionFactory with automatic recovery enabled set to false and assigned it to rabbit template preliminary set back off policy to it. However when I break a rabbit connection before publishing a message to rabbit seems like back off policy doesn't work and the exception is immediately thrown out. Why its not working as expected and thrown without 5s delay.

one more thing is it possible to apply back off policy to connection factory itself in order to enable auto recovery policy without fear of getting errors each 5s in the logs?

```
  Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(requestedHeartbeat);
        factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false);

        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(factory);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setAddress(address1 + ", " + address2);

        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {

        ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(500);
        backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(10);
        backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(10000);

        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
        return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.retry`; you should see messages `Retry: count=n` if you don't see them, it means the `RetryTemplate` is not on the stack - use a debugger to figure out why.

Comment: What is a `RetryPolicy` in your case though?